# Controlling the memory being used by a C++ programme

Tags: c++, memory-management, ram

I have a C++ program that uses a lot of memory before crashing. Can I specify (via commandline or some other hack) that it should use only say 2Gb RAM and not go all the way using up all the memory in the system before crashing?

The program processes a list of input files. Currently I keep track of the file at which the program crashed and then restart the program at the file where it crashed.

I am thinking of something like another program which keeps track of how much memory this particular program uses and killing it if a limit is exceeded. I'm working on Ubuntu 12.10.

**P.S. It seems there is no easy way to do that. Wisdom of the crowd is that the main program should be fixed.**

Comment: The better solution is to fix your C++ program so that it better manages memory. If the memory use keeps increasing until it crashes, you've got major memory leaks that should be fixed. However, as you're asking for "another program" that will monitor the memory use, your question is off-topic here. Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree. But solving that problem will take more time than I have right now. Ultimately I may have to do it if nothing else works. Also added more details to question.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok. I would like to delete the question then until I can make the question acceptable.

Comment: You're "fixing" a horse with a weight problem by shooting the horse and buying a new one rather than a creating a diet regiment. Function, maybe. Practical, hardly.

Comment: Are you sure that the files are being properly closed after being processed?

Comment: @WhozCraig Odd expression... and it sounds like that would mean rewriting the program in order to fix a bug, not trying to hack in some solution to fix the bug - as in this situation.

Comment: @Arrieta yes. The problem is somewhere else (I don't know where). But whatever files it can process it gives correct output.

Comment: @Dave the analogy was meant to relate to killing a rogue process and starting a new one, not because there is an *unknown reason* to do so, but rather because its inconvenient to actually fix what isn't working right. I apologize if the analogy was lost as the vet's office.

Comment: It may give correct output but keep the file contents in memory, that is why I was asking. But you mention you are sure you are closing them (i.e., releasing the resources). Still, a program which crashes due to memory errors is very, very likely leaking memory or resources.

Comment: Finally: post code. If you don't, we are all making wild guesses.

Comment: Wisdom of the crowd will **always** be that your program should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own `operator new` which throws [`bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) (as it normally would when out of memory) when the total allocated exceeds 2gb.

Note that this is bad form to do, and error prone.... there are several ways you can get around going through the global `operator new`. For your 'hack it' purposes, it would probably be sufficient though.

Comment: So your recommended solution to deal with poor, memory leaking code is to add more poor code? Boo.

Comment: @KenWhite No, I don't recommend this solution, but I decided to answer the question directly instead of telling him not to do what he asked for or that he shouldn't have to, as answerers here _looovveee_ to do. Obviously he should just fix his stupid bug instead of do this crap.

Comment: +1 for the self-depricating solution. You called it what it is, which is more than many would do.

Comment: @Dave thanks for the help. This seems like a plausible hack. But I think I will fix the original program.

Answer (score 0):

You'll limit the amount of memory your program uses in your code.

The operating system should be smart enough to do its best to keep your code running (caching things to disk, for example).  Your system performance might grind to a halt, but your code will still execute if there's space on the disk to serve as "extra memory" if you need.

If you pass a parameter in to limit the memory, your code will need to know what to do with it.

But if you're eating up the entire system's memory, that suggests that your approach at least needs some tuning up, or possibly a complete overhaul.  Your algorithms may not be efficient enough to work with reasonable memory constraints.

(This assumes that your code is not leaking memory.  If it is, then fix that.)